# Counters for flags/edits/annotations are "counter"intuitive

Tags: bug, profile-page, flags

In the top bar, there's an orange counter for edits and a yellow counter for flags.
In the user profile, there's a yellow counter for mod annotations and an orange counter for user flags.

**Shouldn't the two *flag counters* both be yellow?** It's confusing that a counter that represents the same aspect (on the site / on the user) has two different colors, *especially* when the same colors are used with unrelated information.

```
pending edits on site  |  pending flags on site
-----------------------+-------------------------
user's mod annotations | total user posts flagged
```

[image]
(The actual numbers in this illustration is a coincidence.)